# mod_rewrite problem with subfolders paths

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

```
From : www.example.com/cut/456
To : www.example.com/cut/index.php?tag=456
```

I try this and it doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /cut/index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: is it `.htaccess`? where is it located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cut/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

It's work with this

Answer (score 1):

unless your `.htaccess` located in `cut` directory, it should be better to use:

```
RewriteRule ^cut/(.+)/?$ /cut/index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

otherwise

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

should do. It seems to be the issue with your substitution string, it's hard to say what exactly is the cause since *doesn't work* is not a sufficient description of a problem.

Comment: The requested URL /cut/15 was not found on this server.

Comment: if it's in a folder shouldn't it be:

RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ ../index.php?tag=$1 [L]

not tested...

Answer (score 1):

Is the server actually loading .htaccess? You can check this by chucking garbage at the end of the file and seeing if you get an error for it.

If it's not, `AllowOverride` is probably set to None somewhere higher in the directory tree. Try declaring a `<Directory /path/to/cut>` somewhere in your Apache's main configuration file and putting `AllowOverride All` in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just expect integer values, you should restrict your pattern to such values:

```
RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]*)$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

The problem with your current pattern is that `^([^/]*)$` does also match `index.php` (`/cut/index.php` without the per-directory path prefix) and thus may cause an infinite loop.